# Module won't get updated in Tour of Heroes Tutorial

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-tour-of-heroes

I am doing the official "Tour of Heroes" Angular tutorial on angular.io.

After adding a module called 'heroes', and showing it, everything was fine. The heroes.component.html only contained one p-tag saying "heroes works!". When I change it, my application will get updated, but it won't update the changes made in heroes.component.html. So, even when nowhere in the project is written "heroes works" anymore, the application still shows that message.
I really appreciate your help.

heroes.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {

 hero = 'windstorm';

 constructor() { }

 ngOnInit() {
 }

}
```

heroes.component.html:

```
<h2>{{hero}}</h2>>
```

app.component.html:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<app-heroes></app-heroes>
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'tour';
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes/heroes.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeroesComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple quick things off the top.

`<h2>{{hero}}</h2>**>**` remove the extra greater than symbol in your component's html file.

Can you send a screen shot of your file structure?

Try opening the app in an Incognito window of Chrome to ensure your cache is fully cleared.

Comment: My friend I have to thank you! After removing that extra symbol and restarting the project, everything works fine. If you would live in Germany, I would share a beer with you!

Comment: I am from the States but do enjoy a fine bier! Prost!